# Small posets with prescribed number of linear extensions

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory

Given a natural number $n$, I want to construct a (finite) poset $P_n$ such that $P_n$ has exactly $n$ [linear extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_extension).

This can always be done, for instance taking $P_n$ to be a chain of length $n-1$ plus a single element that is incomparable to all the others.

However, I would like each $P_n$ to have a "small" number of elements. More specifically, I would like to know if there such a sequence $(P_n)$ such that, for all $n$, $P_n$ has exactly $n$ linear extensions and $|P_n| = O(\log(n))$, where $|P_n|$ is the number of elements of $P_n$. Is there a construction for this, or a way to justify that it cannot be done?

More generally, is anything known about the sequence that maps $n$ to the size of the smallest poset with exactly $n$ linear extensions?

Comment: Did you mean: Is there a sequence of posets $(P_n)$ each of length $O(\log n)$ such each one has exactly $n$ linear extensions?

Comment: @talegari: No I mean that their *sizes* (number of elements) should be $O(\log n)$.

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.2550.

Comment: @RichardStanley: Thanks for pointing this out! I had a look, but I do not see the connection to my question: the paper appears to be about constructing posets with a prescribed number of *open sets* (aka order ideals), but I'm asking about the number of *linear extensions*. Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see a connection between the two?